# Trying to view html on yikyak.com, get "browser out of date" page

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

**Question:** yikyak.com returns some sort of "browser not supported" landing page when I try to view source code in chrome (even for the page I'm logged in on) or when I write it out to the Python terminal. Why is this and what can I do to get around it?

Edit for clarification: I'm using the chrome webdriver. I can navigate around the yik yak website by clicking on it just fine. But whenever I try to see what html is on the page, I get an html page for a "browser not reported" page.

**Background:** I'm trying to access yikyak.com with selenium for python to download yaks and do fun things with them. I know fairly little about web programming.

Thanks!

Secondary, less important question: If you're already here, are there particularly great free resources for a super-quick intro to the certification knowledge I need to store logins and stuff like that to use my logged in account? That would be awesome.

Comment: How did you tried to get source code? I can view it both in `Chrome` and `Firefox`...

Comment: @Andersson: Ctrl-u (in my normal chrome browser) and "print driver.page_source" (in my python code). Both return the html for a page that displays little info beyond a message about my browser being out of date. Are you getting the actual logon screen or a list of yaks in html?

Comment: to use `selenium` you don't need to operate with page full `html` code. Just use mouse right click on required element on page + `inspect` and you'll get `html` code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was being dumb. I saved off the html as a file and opened that file with chrome and it displayed the normal page. I just didn't see the fact that it was a normal page looking at it directly. Thanks all 15 people for your time.